# Javascript looping elements using webdriverIO

Tags: javascript, node.js, webdriver, es6-promise, webdriver-io

*** New to Javascripting ***

How can I loop elements when I get a list of elements in Javascript. Below is how I would do in Java but not sure how I will do with Java scripting.

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='container']"));    
        System.out.println("number of elements: " + elements.size());

        for(WebElement ele : elements){
            //ele.sendKeys("value");
            System.out.println(ele.getText());
            //System.out.println(ele.getAttribute("id"));
            //System.out.println(ele.getTagName());
        }
```

I am able to get elements using `browser.elements`. But I am unsure how I can loop it.

Thanks. Kindly help.

Comment: if `elements.size()` is anything but 0 or 1, you're dealing with invalid HTML anyway

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('#container').forEach(e => console.log(e.textContent))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent in webdriverio would be like this:

```
var elements = browser.elements("//div[@id='container']");

elements.value.forEach(function(el) {
  console.log(browser.elementIdText(el.ELEMENT).value);
});
```

Comment: You can simplify that second part to:
`elements.forEach(function(el) {
  console.log(el.getText());
});`

Comment: No you can't. `browser.elements()` returns an array of WebElement JSON objects. That array is in the `elements.value` property. From the documentation: `The array of elements can be retrieved using the ‘response.value’ which is a collection of element ID’s and can be accessed in the subsequent commands using the ‘.ELEMENT’ method.`

Comment: You're correct that it returns an array of WebElement JSON objects, but WebdriverIO is smart enough to know how to handle that array. I wrote an example that you can run here: http://try.learnwebdriverio.com/share/uOlqeSwhIJWVTgDX

Comment: Well isn't that fancy. What about `.filter()`, `.map()`, `.reduce()`?

Comment: Never mind, I just tried it myself and saw that it worked.